# Foundation 5 Offcanvas does not support in IE 8

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I am having an issue with IE 8 and Foundation 5 offcanvas. The offcanvas sidebar always shows no matter what and overlays the main content. So how can i hide that issue in my website

Comment: IE8 is nearly dead and the recommended way to use Foundation on it is to **stick with version 3**.

Comment: @bodi0 Even more, it will auto-update to the new version. And since viewing website requires working internet connection, you don't need to worry about old versions of the Internet Explorer deep underground in the nuclear bunkers. + Windows XP is out of support and won't receive new patches so even lazy people will upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Use Foundation 3 ([or at least Foundation 4](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/4.3.2/support.html)) because with [Foundation  5](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/compatibility.html) on IE8 You will have multiple issues including unsupported commands from ECMAScript 5. It will cost you a ton of time and degrade reliability of your site.

Comment: foundation 3 not having off-canvas. Here we need off-canvas

Comment: @maheshrocks It will be easier and less time consuming to make your own off-canvas. You can try to port off-canvas from the F5 but you will have multiple compatibility issues.